# Club two table based on certain condition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, gaps-and-islands

Here's my sample input tables:

| employee_id | project | effective_date** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2014-08-13 |
| 1 | B | 2016-12-21 |
| 1 | C | 2018-02-21 |

| employee_id | designation | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | trainee | 2014-08-05 |
| 1 | senior | 2016-08-17 |
| 1 | team leader | 2018-02-05 |

Table1: describes an employee who undergoes different projects at different date's in an organization.

Table2: describes the same employee from Table1 who undergoes different designation in the same organisation.

Now I want an Expected output table like this:

| employee_id | project | designation | effective_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | trainee | 2014-08-13 |
| 1 | A | senior | 2016-08-17 |
| 1 | B | Senior | 2016-12-21 |
| 1 | B | team leader | 2018-02-05 |
| 1 | C | team leader | 2018-02-21 |

The fact is that whenever:

- his project changes, I need to display project effective_date.
- his designation changes, I need to display designation effective_date but with the project he worked on during this designation change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem falls into the gaps-and-islands taxonomy. This specific variant can be solved in three steps:

- applying a `UNION ALL` of the two tables while splitting "*tab1.project*" and "*tab2.role*" in two separate fields within the same schema
- compute the partitions, between a non-null value and following null values, with two running sums (one for the "*designation*" and one for "*project*")
- apply two different aggregations on the two different fields, to remove the null values.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT employee_id, effective_date,
           project        AS project, 
           NULL           AS role         FROM tab1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT employee_id, effective_date, 
           NULL           AS project, 
           designation    AS role         FROM tab2
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN project IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER(
               PARTITION BY employee_id 
               ORDER     BY effective_date
           ) AS project_partition,
           COUNT(CASE WHEN role IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER(
               PARTITION BY employee_id 
               ORDER     BY effective_date
           ) AS role_partition
    FROM cte    
)
SELECT employee_id, effective_date,
       MAX(project) OVER(PARTITION BY project_partition) AS project,
       MAX(role)    OVER(PARTITION BY role_partition)    AS role
FROM cte2
ORDER BY employee_id, effective_date
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ctsvzbQVwXu88MnP8neNY/1).